# Image can't be uploaded using multipart in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to upload images in the database using multipart. But I got an error from API ' Files can't be uploaded". I checked API in postman. It is working fine there. So there must be an issue be my code. I wasn't able to find any bugs. What am I doing wrong?

**Screenshot of Error** - https://prnt.sc/ss6ecp

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const URL="https://api.hello.com/admin/fetch_image_settings";

const POST_URL="https://api.hello.com/admin/save_image_settings";

const header = {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
}



class ImageSetting extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            logo_image:null,
            app_icon:null,
            favicon:null,
            admin_id:localStorage.getItem("admin_id"),
            website:null

    }
    }
    handleFile=(event)=>
    {
        let file=event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.files[0]});
    }
    handleInput=(event)=>
    {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }
    handleSubmit=(event)=>
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { logo_image, app_icon,favicon, website, admin_id}=this.state;
        let data=new FormData();
        data.append("logo_image",logo_image);
        data.append("app_icon",app_icon);
        data.append("favicon",favicon);

        axios.post(POST_URL,{data},{
            params:{
                admin_id, website
            },
            headers:header
        })
        .then((res)=>
        {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err)=>
        {
            console.log(err);
        })

    }
    componentDidMount()
    {
        const { admin_id}=this.state;
        axios.get(URL,{
            params:{
                admin_id
            }
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch((err)=>
        {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <h1>Image setting</h1>
            <form name="image-setting" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.website} onChange={this.handleInput} name="website" placeholder="Website" />
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile} name="logo_image" />
                <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile} name="app_icon" />
                <input type="file"  onChange={this.handleFile} name="favicon" />
            </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
export default ImageSetting;
```

Comment: Did you try debug api ? you say that error come from api.

Comment: API works perfectly fine in postman. I got status code 200 and then error message 'File can't be uploaded". It suggests that API is working perfectly fine.

Comment: the status is 200 and how the error is returned ? . can you debug api ?

Comment: let me attach the screenshot of error message from api

Comment: @Bahtiyar, i added the api error screenshot

Comment: ok I didn't mean that. You can call Api successfully. so statu is 200. But api returns you an error message. can you debug in api? Isn't it an api you wrote?

Comment: I debug API in postman. It works perfectly fine there.

Comment: you should see the POST body in your web development tools. there must be a difference between the Postman POST and the `axios` POST. maybe try `axios.post(POST_URL, data, {` without bracelets around data.

Comment: I don't know how, but it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue must be with letter case. It should look like `Content-Type` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

An object can contain properties with same name but different case.

```js
const header = {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}

console.log(header)
```